# IIS issues challenge on unprotected directory

Tags: iis, authentication, iis-7.5

We've encountered an issue where IIS issues a challenge for all directories on the site, including the ones which are marked to allow anonymous users. This only happens when accessing the site through HTTPS. When the site is accessed via HTTP, challenges are only issued when authentication is required.

The directory structure is similar to this:

```
  /
  +--secure
  +--unsecure
```

The root folder is configured so all users are authorized, both anonymous and digest authentication are enabled.
The "secure" folder is configured so that anonymous users are denied.

Initially, IIS issues a challenge to Firefox, regardless of the directory. IE and Chrome only receive challenges in the "secure" directory.

After logging out from the client machine and logging back in, only IE experiences the expected behavior, Chrome and Firefox receive challenges in all directories.

One other possibly relevant detail. The server where this occurs uses a subdomain, so the URL is www.dev.mydomain.com, but the wildcard SSL certificate is issued to *.mydomain.com.  Using a self-signed certificate on another server, we can't duplicate the problem.

**Update:** We've discovered that turning off the default document causes the problem to go away (re-enabling causes it to return). It's a workaround, but we'd prefer to know the true cause.  This has the scent of an IIS bug combined with IE knowing some "secret handshake" the other browsers don't.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you specify a sub sub domain (www.dev.mydomain.com) which may be the cause.  Per the specs wildcard certs only work with one level subdomains (ie mysite.mydomain.com and not test1.mysite.mydomain.com).

Comment: We thought about that, but putting the wildcard certificate on another server with sub-sub-domains didn't allow us to reproduce the error.  It seems to be something about this one machine's setup.